# Can Active Record running with HTML tag ? [YII]

Tags: php, html, yii

I have a form like this as yii active record :

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'arsip-perihal-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>    
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nama_arsip'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'nama_arsip',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nama_arsip'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kode_primary'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'kode_primary',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'kode_primary'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Keterangan'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Keterangan'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Keterangan'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Can I use a HTML tag, An example textbox

```
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
```

if it can, how to use it? how to set default from $model like the form above?

Thank You,

Comment: you can use, run the yii form, view source how HTML input elements are generated, just do copy past. But this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$form->textField`, CActiveForm generates a textbox with `ModelName[attributeName]` name. So you can provide name for your textbox with this structure.

```
<input type="text" name="ModelName[fname]">
```

Note, "ModelName" is your model class, for example, "User".